# Dispatch an action onBlur with redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, onblur

i have an input component which i made compatible with redux form like this:

```
const renderInput = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div className="input-row">
    <div>
      <input
        {...input}
        className="form-control input-box__input"
        type={type}
        placeholder={label}
        autoComplete="off"
        onBlur={input.onBlur}
      />
      {touched && error &&
      <span className="error">
        <FormattedMessage
          id={`${error}`}
          defaultMessage={`_${error}_`}
          description={`the message for the ${error}`}
        />
      </span>}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

And i using it like this:

```
<Field
              name="username"
              type="text"
              component={renderInput}
              onBlur={value => usernameClickHandler(value)}
            />
```

When i leave the field the action was never been dispatched.
What am i missing?

The action is being dispatched here:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  {
    submitSecondRegister: (secondRegisterData) => {
      dispatch(secondRegister(secondRegisterData));
    },
    usernameClickHandler: (name) => {
      dispatch(userNameExistence(name));
    }
  }
);
```

All i see is that the action is never dispatched. I assume that my onBlur is not working

Comment: Can you show the code for `usernameClickHandler`?

Comment: is `usernameClickHandler` defined somewhere?

Comment: Yes it is defined in the component's props. And via mapDispatchToProps in the container i'm make it a prop

Comment: @jakee of course...const mapDispatchToprops=(dispatch) => usernameClickHandler(name): => dispatch(usernameAction(name))

Comment: Can you add that code to the question itself along with the component code surrounding the `Field` that's not working?